# Change parent of item in list

Tags: c#, .net, list

I have this small test 
I want NOT copy item of a list a other.

My Idea is set parent to specific item(s). Something how set handle (how pointers)

Why?

Because my items is relationship to specific objects and i want have available move this object betweeen parents

In this test i only did copy items and not set parent how i wanted

it is posible and how, please

```
    [Test]
    public void ProbarList()
    {

        var products = new List<Product>()
                           {
                               new Product() {Id = 1, Descripcion = "Cerveza"},
                               new Product() {Id = 2, Descripcion = "Cigarro"},
                               new Product() {Id = 3, Descripcion = "Cafe"}
                           };

        var copiaProductos = new List<Product>();

        copiaProductos.Insert(copiaProductos.Count, products[0]);

        Assert.True(copiaProductos[0].Id == 1,"Bag of copyofproducts is empty");
        Assert.True(products.Count == 2,"The list of products still have 3 items");
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

I looks like you want to remove from one list and add to another. If I have the requirement correct, then it is simple.

```
Product product = products[0]; // retrieve product at specific index
products.RemoveAt(0); // remove at same index
copiaProductos.Add(product); // add product to different list
```

Comment: Yes, that is but not. If have do remove a products so means what really no change parent instead this create an copy.

Comment: @Carlos Com: Your English is very difficult to understand. I can't figure out what you are trying to say here.